# How to get product id from product url in magento 2

Tags: magento2

In Magento 1, I was able to get the product id from the product url:

```
$product_id = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')
                ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->loadByRequestPath(basename($url))
                ->getProductId();
```

But I can't find similar solution in magento 2. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
//$this->productUrlRewriteResource is the instance of \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Product
$connection = $this->productUrlRewriteResource->getConnection();
$table      = $this->productUrlRewriteResource->getTable('url_rewrite');
$select     = $connection->select();
$select->from($table, ['entity_id'])
    ->where('entity_type = :entity_type')
    ->where('request_path LIKE :request_path');

$result = $connection->fetchCol(
    $select,
    ['entity_type' => 'product', 'request_path' => basename($url)]
);
$productId     = isset($result[0]) ? $result[0] : null;
```

From this you can get product id by request path.